# position fixed div in iframe not working

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am working on facebook iframe application . I have one pop up message box inside this application. That pop up is having fixed possition . But its not working as added inside iframe having no scroll.

Is it possible to make pop up fixed in position if its in the iframe having no scroll?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible to make pop up fixed in position if its in the iframe having no scroll?

Nope - the `iframe` is a document in itself. Anything with `position: fixed` in there is *not* fixed relative to the main document.

If you want something to be fixed relative to the main document, you need to put it into the main document - either directly, or by copying the node using JavaScript (using jQuery is a good idea in such a case.)

For the latter to work, both the main document and the iframed document need to be on the same protocol, port, and domain.