# Bootstrap 4 Modal overlay not appearing centered in the viewport through Iframe

Tags: iframe, safari, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, mobile-safari

I've made an app written in VueJs with Bootstrap 4. When a modal popup appears in the viewport it is centered as an overlay.

When I view that application through an `<iframe>` at **Safari Mobile Version 12**, the content appears correctly inside it and the modal popup  is at the top (y-axis) of the viewport but it is not centered at the mobile screen and the user has to scroll to the top in order to see it.

I also tested it at a Desktop Safari to simulate this behaviour and works fine.
This is the iframe code I use and the css rules.

```html
<html>
 <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="Games">
      <style>
         html, body, iframe {
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }
         body { 
             overflow: hidden; 
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <iframe src="https://domain/path/to/ΜοbileGames" frameborder="no"> 
   </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've tested some css for the iframe and i couldn't make it. Any idea ?

Comment: Possibly this can provide a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805274/bootstrap-modal-at-top-of-iframe-regardless-of-scroll-position-how-do-i-positio?